# How to get the type of geometry column in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, geometry

I need to determine the type of geometry column and doing it with the following query:

```
SELECT type 
FROM   geometry_columns 
WHERE  f_table_schema = 'public' 
       AND f_table_name = 'table_name' 
       AND f_geometry_column = 'col_name'
```

It works fine for regular geometries, like Point or Polygon. But then there are also some fancy geometries like PointZ. How do I determine if column has it? Above mentioned query returns just POINT for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `geometry_columns` view takes care to remove any Z/M suffixes.

You can look up the PostGIS type modifier directly in the system tables:

```
SELECT postgis_typmod_type(atttypmod)
FROM pg_attribute
WHERE attrelid = 'public.table_name'::regclass
  AND attname = 'col_name';
```

(The same can be done with `postgis_typmod_srid()`.)

Answer (score 0):

I found that `geometry_columns` stores dimension info in another column - `coord_dimension`:

```
SELECT type, coord_dimension 
FROM   geometry_columns 
WHERE  f_table_schema = 'public' 
       AND f_table_name = 'trafic_lights' 
       AND f_geometry_column = 'position'
```

It is even better since it contains a **number of dimensions** directly!